# Why people have less hair than other primates?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, zoology

Well as you can figure out, most primates such as monkeys, gorillas and chimpanzees, have all their body covered with fur. As we know they are evolutional "relatives" to us humans, but we dont have much hair(only on the head,on the armpits, on the groin, etc.). I would like to know why this "evolution" happened in a such brief era and why.

Comment: Why are "relatives" and "evolution" in quotes?

Comment: Because their DNA (and more specificly the monkeys DNA) isnt much similar with the human one. If u want you can edit my question.

Comment: You obviously haven't been to many beaches, especially Greek ones. There are many people out there that are quite hairy, with uninterrupted hair from the top of the head to the top of the feet. All mammals are covered with hair (the thickness varies, of course), even whales and dolphins. You also have another misconception, about DNA differences - the sequences of humans and monkeys are *very* similar, which is why we use them in medical studies for efficacy and toxicity. Finally, the last common ancestor between humans and great apes was ~7.5 million years ago, not a "brief era" at all.

Comment: @Orphee From the phrasing of your question and especially from your comment, it feels like you could make good use of a short and very introductory source of information about evolutionary biology such as [Understanding Evolution by UC Berkeley](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) for example.

Comment: @Remi.b I had read a small article about human and its evolution at dw.com, so these are only my knowledge.

Comment: Hence my recommendation. It is not a necessary a priori for asking question, not at all. But it would quickly increase your knowledge and your ability to ask further questions about evolution incl. human evolution.